# JS phone validation. Adding formatting

Tags: javascript, validation

I have some validation I'm using in a form input field for phone numbers. I'm having trouble with two parts of it. The first is that I wan't is to add an opening parenthesis. Secondly, I wan't it to keep the parenthesis and dash marks even when I perform a backspace. Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/8/

```
window.mask = function (e,f){
    var len = f.value.length;
    var key = whichKey(e);
    if((key>47 && key<58) || (key>96 && key<105))
    {
        if( len==1 )f.value='('+f.value
        else if(len==3 )f.value=f.value+')'
        else if(len==7 )f.value=f.value+'-'
        else f.value=f.value;
    }
    else{
        f.value = f.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/,'')
        f.value = f.value.replace('--','-')
    }
}

function whichKey(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    return code
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onkeydown="mask(event,this)" onkeyup="mask(event,this)" maxlength="12" />
```

Comment: opening parenthesis exists already, I don't get it

Comment: @imbondbaby Look at the jsfiddle

Comment: I did, I see a parenthesis

Comment: @imbondbaby But did you test it out? The parenthesis disappears after the second keystroke. That's the point I'm making.

Comment: Not on my end... This is how I see it http://i59.tinypic.com/vcvs6f.png... Would you like it some other format?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `else` statement from the JavaScript.

**Change to this:**

```
window.mask = function (e,f){
    var len = f.value.length;
    var key = whichKey(e);
    if((key>47 && key<58) || (key>96 && key<105))
    {
        if( len==1 )f.value='('+f.value
        else if(len==3 )f.value=f.value+')'
        else if(len==7 )f.value=f.value+'-'
        else f.value=f.value;
    }
}

function whichKey(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    return code
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

For anybody wondering, I got this to work by 1)removing the else statement (that fixed the issues with backspaces) and 2) changing all `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=` (this fixed the disappearing opening parenthesis for cases where keystroke was 0 or 9).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/21/